# spark-submit.sh returns 0 if job fails

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to automate running the `spark-submit.sh` script by another application. However, I noticed that even though spark-submit is aware of an error (it reports `ERROR: Job failed.`),  it returns zero, which indicates that the `spark-submit.sh` script completed successfully. See:

```
./spark-submit.sh --vcap .vcap.json --deploy-mode cluster --master ...
To see the log, in another terminal window run the following command:
tail -f spark-submit_1463130693N.log

...

ERROR: Job failed.
Log file: spark-submit_1463130693N.log
snowch$ echo $?
0
```

I could parse the output from the `spark-submit.sh` script for the ERROR message, however that isn't very robust.  Am I using the correct version?

```
snowch$ ./spark-submit.sh --version
spark-submit.sh  VERSION : '1.0.0.0.20160420.1'
```

Is this a bug with the `spark-submit.sh` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the right version. It is a bug. It should return error code for that case.

Comment: Thanks @Anh.  It should be easy to fix this one, just needs an `exit 1` between line 1097 and 1098.  However, there are probably a few other places `exit 1` is needed such as after 1071, 1078 : https://github.com/snowch/bluemix-spark-submit-examples/blob/master/spark-submit.sh

Comment: .. also needs `exit 1` at line 781.